# Improve StackExchange link markup

Tags: regex

I recently posted an answer with the following link:

https://cache-elastic-pandora.ecn.cl/emol/noticia/_search?q=publicada:true+AND+ultimoMinuto:true+AND+seccion:*+AND+temas.id:*&sort=fechaModificacion:desc&size=15&from=45

Actual link here:

```
https://cache-elastic-pandora.ecn.cl/emol/noticia/_search?q=publicada:true+AND+ultimoMinuto:true+AND+seccion:*+AND+temas.id:*&sort=fechaModificacion:desc&size=15&from=45
```

And was surprised that StackOverflow isn't able to accurately mark-up this hyperlink.

I know this isn't comprehensive (and missing quite a bit), but even a very crude regex up until a space, with a negative lookbehind to remove ending punctuations, is able to capture this:

```
https?:\/\/[^\s]+(?<![,.)\]?!])
```

https://regex101.com/r/9ZblaL/2/

Does anyone know what the StackExchange link-markup uses? And what might be a better regex that can be used to parse basic web links?

**Update:** I think the link itself has characters that are being interpreted as markup and then stripped before the link itself is being constructed (for example, the character `*`).

Comment: You can probably trace it back to `Markdown.Converter` near the top of wmd.en.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression that SE uses is:

[`(="|<)?\b(https?|ftp)(:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|[\]()!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|[\])])(?=$|\W)`](https://regex101.com/r/v28mQo/1)

which is [constructed from](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/wmd.en.js) (around line 1530):

```
    var charInsideUrl = "[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|[\\]()!:,.;]",
        charEndingUrl = "[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|[\\])]",
        autoLinkRegex = new RegExp("(=\"|<)?\\b(https?|ftp)(://" + charInsideUrl + "*" + charEndingUrl + ")(?=$|\\W)", "gi"),
```

Your URL isn't fully matched because the `*` is not part of the `charInsideUrl` character set. Fix that (add `*` to the character set), and the pattern matches your entire URL.

Asterisks [*are*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) officially permitted in query strings, so I don't immediately see anything wrong with just adding them to the character set.

Comment: right I see. I think they might not use the `*` because precedence is given to using that as markup, for example with *italics* (`*italics*`) so i'm guessing it's intentional on their part, but maybe not...

Comment: I'm pretty sure links are processed *before* italics and bold, see line ~561: `text = _DoAutoLinks(text);
            
            text = text.replace(/Â§P/g, "://"); // put in place to prevent autolinking; reset now
            
            text = _EncodeAmpsAndAngles(text);
            text = _DoItalicsAndBold(text);` where `_DoAutoLinks` turns the substrings that *look* like URLs into true `<a>`s.